# Need help extracting/parsing list of elements from an http asp page

Tags: java, asp.net, html

I have the following html code from an url, and i'm trying to get the **comboList2** in java, but i cannot get that data, I'm using jsoup lib to do this, but not succeded to do that :(, anyone can help me with with this. BTW, i've tried using the id, but i need to get first the element background, then get element header, then get top element... and so on until i get the upMenu element, and then i dont know how to get the list. Is there a way to do this?

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="logo"> some stuff here </div>
      <div id="contMenus">
        <div id="combos">
          <div id="upMenu">
            <div class="comboList1"> </div>
            <div class="comboList2">
              <select name="listName" onchange="" id="listID" class="combo" onBlur="" onMouseDown="">
                <option value="0">Element 1</option>
                <option value="1">Element 2</option>
                <option value="2">Element 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [jakarta jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html), it's fast and robust.